# Scaling armature glitch?

Tags: rigging

So I have a rigged model that I'm going to use in a scene, but it is too big. I treys to scale down the armature, but then when I try to pose it, the head and neck return to the original size leaving the body small. I've tried scaling everything in edit mode but I don't think all the bones are being selected. I can't scale it in pose mode because a lot of the bones have locks on the transform things. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to apply the scale (ctrl + A then scale) for both the armature and the model ?

Comment: Yes I have. I get the same result.

Comment: Hard to guess without the file... you can upload it here if you want http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. Or another suggestion : do you have IK ?

Comment: I can't upload it as I doesn't belong to me, sorry. Yes it does have IK.

Comment: Is there a separate head rig parented to the say head bone of the body rig?  A screenshot or two would be handy, rig expanded in outliner for instance.  As lemon commented applying scale to the armature will scale all bones in the rig.   Any existing poses / actions will also need to be rescaled to match.

Comment: No it's all one rig. All the objects and curves for simulating the hair are parented to the armature. There aren't any poses or actions.

Comment: Indicate the name if you respond to someone using @ plus the <user name>, @batFINGER (if not, I am not sure he has the notification)